Why am I getting 'No matching distribution found' for torch_xla~=2.5.0 when installing to be used for a TPU?
I'm working on a research project and intend to install PyTorch XLA to utilize GCP TPUs. I ran the following command to install a stable build, built just for TPUs (no CUDA involved; as listed here on the official README for the package). This is intended to work on my local machine (listed below) to use Cloud TPUs while working on a setup environment (hence the TPU VM-specific setup) :
pip install torch~=2.5.0 torch_xla[tpu]~=2.5.0 -f https://storage.googleapis.com/libtpu releases/index.html -f https://storage.googleapis.com/libtpu-wheels/index.html

However, I am encountering the following error (default torch installation works as intended):
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch_xla~=2.5.0 (from versions: none) 
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch_xla~=2.5.0  

I tried the following troubleshooting steps:

Verified by Python version and platform compatibility with the package.

Updated pip to the latest version to ensure compatibility with newer distributions.

The proper index URLs for torch_xla and the TPU wheels were added as per the installation instructions.

Checked for typos in the package name and confirmed the version existed.

Attempted installation in a clean virtual environment.  Ensured no network or SSL issues were affecting the installation.

Verified that no conflicting dependencies were present and tried --force-reinstall.
I expected the package to install successfully after following these steps. However, I still encountered the same error above


Details:

Computer: ASUS Vivobook S15 (Copilot + PC); ARM64 Device

Environment: Running on TPU using WSL2 Ubuntu 22.04.

Python Version: 3.12.x (checked compatibility with torch_xla version).

While the CUDA version of the package (i.e. the wheels/dependencies added onto PyTorch XLA for both TPU and Nvidia GPU-based development) shows prerequisites/versions (including Python), there wasn't one for just a stable build of the TPU VM (no CUDA involved).


This leads me to another question: Where could I also find the list of prereqs for installing this (as the latest updates/master documentation show no change in versions besides this issue of the guide for installation?

Command Details: I included the links for TPU-specific wheels (libtpu-releases and libtpu-wheels).
From my understanding, torch_xla should have a version compatible with torch 2.5.0, but it seems no distribution is available for my setup.



"Python Version: 3.12.6 (checked compatibility with torch_xla version)." In the original question the text said "checked compatibility with torch version". That perhaps was true. But it's not true about torch_xla: it requires a different version of Python. Please do real check.

There are no wheels available for Python 3.12 as can be seen here. Even the stable release (i.e. torch-xla 2.5.1) doesn't have wheels for Python 3.12 See files.
To install torch-xla 2.5.0, you'd have to downgrade to Python 3.11 as there are wheels available for Linux distributions for Python 3.9 - 3.11.
Then install PyTorch/XLA in a new TPU VM:
pip install torch~=2.5.0 torch_xla[tpu]~=2.5.0 -f https://storage.googleapis.com/libtpu-releases/index.html

Or the stable build in a new TPU VM:
pip install torch==2.5.1 torch_xla[tpu]==2.5.1 -f https://storage.googleapis.com/libtpu-releases/index.html

See torch-xla 2.5.1

Hey again! Thanks for the help!
I tried doing that (I used Python 3.10.15), but the same issue persists. Could it be something regarding my use of an ARM64 device or the fact I am trying to set it up for a TPU VM? Even if it is the latter, I get this same error if I try the default install (without the tpu marker).
